# what is kernel managed memory and how can reduce memory?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, low-memory

As im newbie to memory management and memory usage in linux . This question may be very trivial . 
still Here i have some doubts. Please suggest me if im wrong.

From `cat /proc/meminfo` which list memory usage and availability.

from this i can get to know Total avilabe RAM , free ram and many more of system.From this i can derive kernel manage memory .

`Kernel Managed = MemTotal - (MemFree + Bufferes + Cached + AnonPages)`

suppose from meminfo i hv below values.

Kernel Managed = 384.26M -(250.43M+ 1.73M+ 43.71M+71M)=17.4M

if `kernel managed memory=17.4MB` .

1)What exactly This Kernel managed memory means?  How kernel is managing this memory where all it using?

2)Is it possible to reduce this memory e.g from 17MB to 12MB or still less?If so how i can do it?

Comment: If you don't have a fairly deep understanding of kernel memory management, it's almost always best to just let the kernel do its thing. Do you have a specific reason for wanting to tweak this?

Comment: /proc/slabinfo will have details on where some of the memory is used. https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-slabinfo.html  .

Comment: @KirbyTodd i need to reduce the memory usage out of 512MB now im getting 200MB to 250MB free so i need reduce atleast 50 to 70 mb free. now system-125Mb kernel-20mB reserved-127MB etc. is there any possible to make some free memory in kernel and reserved memory. how can i tune it.